# For each issue, run-time error 6, overflow

Tags: excel, vba

the below code is working perfectly but when i added the "'" code the code will stop after n number of loop related for each (rng1) giving an error of overflow run-time error 6

Appreciate if you can help me and if there is any possibility to optimize the code, thank you

the below code is working perfectly but when i added the "'" code the code will stop after n number of loop related for each (rng1) giving an error of overflow run-time error 6

Appreciate if you can help me and if there is any possibility to optimize the code, thank you

```
Sub Count()

Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim CountRecords As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim UniquePercentage As Integer
Dim SumOfUniqueness As Integer
Dim CountOfUniqueness As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim LastPosition As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Please Select Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .ButtonName = "Confirm"
    If .Show = -1 Then
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Else
        End
    End If
End With





    sh.Cells.ClearContents

    myFile = Dir(myPath)



i = 1

Do While myFile <> ""
    sh.Cells(1, 1) = "Table Name"
    sh.Cells(i + 1, 1) = myFile
    sh.Cells(1, 2) = "Count of records"
    sh.Cells(1, 3) = "Uniqueness"
    Count = Count + 1
    myFile = Dir
    i = i + 1
Loop

j = 1

For i = 1 To Count
    sh.Activate
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    FilePath = myPath & Range("A" & j + 1).Value
    Workbooks.Open FilePath
    Worksheets("Properties").Activate
    CountRecords = Sheets("Properties").Range("C15").Value
    Worksheets("Column Profile").Activate

    LastPosition = Range("D10").End(xlDown).Row - 2

    For Each rng In Range("D10:D" & LastPosition)
    rng.Value = Replace(rng, "-", "0")
    rng.Value = CInt(rng)
    Next rng

    'For Each rng1 In Range("E10:E" & LastPosition)
    'rng1.Value = Replace(rng1, "-", "0")
    'rng1.Value = CInt(rng1)
    'Next rng1


    CountOfUniqueness = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E10:E" & LastPosition), 0)


    SumOfUniqueness = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D10:D" & LastPosition))


    UniquePercentage = SumOfUniqueness / CountOfUniqueness

    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)


    sh.Activate
    Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("B" & j + 1).Value = CountRecords
    Range("C" & j + 1).Value = UniquePercentage
    j = j + 1
Next i

    If i = 1 Then
    MsgBox("There are no items in this folder:" & Dir(myPath))
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Switching from `Integer` to `Long` might fix the overflow error. `Integer` is mostly just a legacy type. There is seldom a good reason to use it.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: I tried to remove the duplication in text at start of issue but its not working, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Shrotter i have quoted 4 lines (the 2nd for each) when i run the code it stop giving the mentioned error, although if i use the first for each alone it runs with no error

appreciate your help

Comment: @MazenSaie And in which line exactly? Try using `CLng` instead of `CInt`

Comment: You are right, it was line CInt, ill try CLng when ill get back home, thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you issue fixed, appreciated